# DataDog monitoring HTTP calls

Tags: datadog

I have one endpoint where it will provide token which expires in X minutes. This endpoint checks validation of existing token(whether expired or not) and creates new or send back old one.

I have added loggers in code to get the time in mill seconds to get the token & it is showing that token not expired so retuned old one and took 1 ms. But if I see the Datadog traces the time taken to process the request is nearly 500 ms for the http call.

How can we analyze this discrepancy. Can we do it in Datadog ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datadog [Synthetic Monitoring](https://www.datadoghq.com/product/synthetic-monitoring/#api-tests) to create API tests that will show you more information about things like network timing. There is a [guide to creating an API test](https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/synthetics/api_test/).